# How to add a css class and give style in asp.net page or its code behind

Tags: asp.net, css, styles, stylesheet, code-behind

I am using a asp.net aspx page which has a master page. There is a custom control and it does not have cssClass attributes or style attribute. It autogenerates div ids and i want to assign a css just for that aspx page. The tricky part is the id generates by other pages as well. I cannot set this css in my stylesheet because of that reason. any help, greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will want to post some of the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` if you want ID to be fixed. But you want to make sure IDs won't collide each other.

[ClientIDMode in ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)